# Download and save image when app launch for later use (table view)

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm new to objective c. What I am trying to do is that I have a `tableView` which downloads the images from the internet (using `dataWithContentsOfURL`) and a custom cell. When the cell is clicked it will push to another view where it shows that image again. Everything works perfectly fine. However, what I do is to re download the image using the exactly same method i.e.`dataWithContentsOfURL` in the detail view. It is very slow and wasting resource. I am thinking is there any better way to do it, such as downloading all the images I need, and save it in the app somewhere (does not have a clue how to do it), and pull it out later and push to another view).
Please correct me, if my concept is wrong.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to try and create your own solution to storing images in a cache. StackOverflow is for help with very specific programming problems and yours is too broad. That aside, I recommend that you start by using `AFNetworking` to download images, as it makes caching very easy and you'll find an instant increase in performance. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks Guy! I will try look up the caching. Any good example you would recommend for me?

Comment: Like I said, use `AFNetworking`: https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking